# Unable to get results using jsonp and openweathermap api following tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

While following a tutorial to use the openweathermap api using jquery and an ajax call, I'm unable to get results and see the following error in chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, here is my JS code which i'm adding into a JS file to use in index.html:

```js
const apiKey = '9f15d4ade842c933c2675067904450f0';
$(document).ready(function () {
  let searchKey = '';
  $('#submit').click(function () {
    let location = $('#location').val();
    if (!isNaN(location)) {
      searchKey = 'zip';
    } else {
      searchKey = 'q';
    }

    if (location) {
      console.log('here');
      $.ajax({
        name:
          'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?' +
          searchKey +
          '=' +
          location +
          '&appid=' +
          apiKey,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
          const result = outputData(data);
          $('#outputData').html(result);
          $('#outputData').val('');
        },
      });
      function outputData(data) {
        return (
          '<div><h2>Weather in ' + data.name + '</h2>' + '</div>'
        );
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `$.ajax({name...`   should be `$.ajax({url:..`

Comment: The person in the tutorial put "name" instead of "url" - I will try this though.

Comment: Ok that did work, thanks. Can you explain why or how please? It would be good to understand @charlietfl

Comment: Because that's how $.ajax works. If they use name it was a mistake See the docs. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({name... should be $.ajax({url:..
```

(answer given in comments)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post,

Comment: @AlexRudenko do you happen to know a good explanation? it would be helpful.

Comment: there's a link to Ajax documentation - also in the comments above